# how to display randomly figures via JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, random, jquery-isotope, figures

ok, I've set up a [site](http://www.berryadv.gr) and I'm using [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co) for some cool transitions, based on filter options.

however, as isotope loads after the whole page is loaded, and not when the DOM is ready, I cannot use the random display feature, as my figures are displayed for half a second as they are coded, and after the page kinda refreshes and displays my figures randomly.

that's not acceptable. so, I searched a bit for random-displayers for HTML elements, but unfortunately nothing came useful enough.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to hide the content until isotope is loaded. Just having `visibility: hidden` until isotope is ready should suffice. Show some progress indicator during this loading time.